# How to align textboxed on left and right sides

Tags: fonts, gimp

I want to create a shirt design using the same message like this shirt:

[image]

Therefor I need to align both text box edges and the edges of both red blocks. I tried to do this in GIMP, however only centering the text is not solving my issue. Is there a source for templates to create such designs on GIMP? I couldn't find anything searching the web.

Sub questions: What is the name of this basic design? I couldn't find a name of if online. But I know that this is a very traditional design.

Note: I'm new to GIMP, so maybe this is easy to solve and a newbie issue. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't understand what exactly is the problem, can you [edit] your question to add a screenshot of your result / explain in more details? Also I don't think there's a name for this 'design', it's just text.

Answer (score 1):

The [`ofn-text-along-path`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-path-tools/files/scripts/) script can align text along a path, and one of the alignment options is to justify the text over the path "stroke". There is even a "multi" option where it will align several lines of text each over a stroke of the target path:

In blue, the strokes of the initial path, in red the resulting path (some guides (not show) have been used of course to ensure that all path strokes are aligned).

[image]

Comment: This seems to be the perfect solution to my problem. I'll try to apply it later and accept the answer later if it solved my issue. Big thank you so far!

Comment: Can you give a hint on how to open the plugin after I added the folder where ```.py``` file is in to the preferences? :/

Comment: Open the Path list, right click on the path with the guide strokes (the on in blue above), there should be a Tools submenu. The plugin comes with a HTML doc, read it... Also, some hints [here](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-ofn-text-along-path)